# Pip, pip3, and conflicting python distributions

Tags: python, linux, gcc, anaconda, fpic

I am having trouble installing the python packages PyTransit and ktransit to Anaconda 3 (on Linux). It seems like lots of others have had similar errors, but none of their solutions have worked for me. There's a bunch of stuff going on:

`pip install ktransit` gives:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/name/anaconda3/lib/libgfortran.a(pause.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/home/name/anaconda3/lib/libgfortran.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would try to use ./configure with --enable-shared, but there's no config file. I tried adding `extra_compile_args = ["-fPIC"], extra_link_args=["-fPIC"]` to setup.py (as in https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/851), but that did nothing.

`pip install pytransit` gives different errors:

```
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \

Warning: src/gimenez.f90:35: Illegal preprocessor directive
    Warning: src/gimenez.f90:36: Illegal preprocessor directive
    Warning: src/gimenez.f90:37: Illegal preprocessor directive
    src/gimenez.f90:271.33:

        real(8), dimension(CHUNK_SIZE, npol) :: d
                                     1
    Error: Symbol 'chunk_size' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Here's where it gets interesting.  Using pip3 (or sudo pip) allows ktransit to install successfully, but does nothing for pytransit. Pip and pip3 seem to be tied to different places:

```
which pip
/home/name/anaconda3/bin/pip

 which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

which python
/home/name/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Lastly, When I try to import ktransit in a jupyter notebook through anaconda, it fails, but when I import ktransit in the Jupyter QtConsole, it succeeds, but seems to contain itself and not provide actual functionality. What I mean is that I can't reference anything within the module, and:

```
Help on package ktransit:

NAME
    ktransit

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    ktransit (package)
    setup

FILE
    (built-in)
```

I'm thinking that whatever version of python is associated with /usr/bin is somehow messing with me...or maybe there's something wrong with my gcc or libgfortran? I have gcc versions 4.8.5 and 6 (gcc --version gives 4.8.5, but -update-alternatives says there's only one version, 6).

Thanks for taking the time to read this far. I would be very grateful for any suggestions or ideas!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to install, but am surprised that you're using pip and pip3. Find out what version of Python you need and stick to it. I'd suggest undoing what you did so far and starting with a clean slate. And you can then update your question so it's focused on one Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -- I uninstalled Anaconda, made sure my python was pointing in the right direction, and then used sudo python -m pip install. Thank you to Nagev for pushing me to get rid of Anaconda!